# How to set the horizontal orientation for Scroll Choise

Tags: android

I work with the Scroll Choise and try to place them horizontally for more convenience.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <com.webianks.library.scroll_choice.ScrollChoice
        android:id="@+id/scroll_choice1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />



</LinearLayout>
```

but I don't want to use ScrollView, because I have to add 100 TextViews

Comment: please provide code when your posting an issue

Answer (score 0):

It's well simple to implement this. HorizontalScrollView is literally a replicate of ScrollView...

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

//Place only one element within the layout as it will behave like a ScrollView

</HoHorizontalScrollView>
```

Might be worth reading into [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView)
Any questions, feel free to ask...

Comment: I have to add 100 text views

Comment: it is not convenient for me to use Scroll View

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов so in which element is your data stored right now? ScrollChoice?

Comment: Yes, it does not need to add other "View"